# Java Generics compilation error: incompatible types: Item#1 cannot be converted to Item#2

Tags: java, generics, collections, iterator, iterable

I am building my own *collection* class implementing the `Iterable` interface in Java. However, I am getting a compilation error saying:

```
Nikolass-MacBook-Pro:week2 nburk$ javac Deque.java 

Deque.java:115: error: incompatible types: Item#1 cannot be converted to Item#2
         Item currentItem = current.item;
                                   ^
  where Item#1,Item#2 are type-variables:
    Item#1 extends Object declared in class Deque
    Item#2 extends Object declared in class Deque.DequeIterator
1 error
```

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
public class Deque<Item> implements Iterable<Item>  {

   // return an iterator over items in order from front to end
   public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
      return new DequeIterator<Item>();
   }

   private class DequeIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item> {

      public DequeIterator() {

      }

      public Item next () {
         Item currentItem = current.item; // this line causes the ERROR
         current = current.next;
         return currentItem;
      }
   }
}
```

I believe the issue somewhat is due to the fact that I am using the generics in a wrong way and my declaration of `Item` might not be correct. However, I was comparing my implementation with [this quick tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/implementing-iterable.html) and don't see any differences that might cause the issue on my side. Does anybody what I'm missing and how I can get rid of the error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In

```
private class DequeIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item> {
    public DequeIterator() {
    }
}
```

you're declaring a **new** type variable called `Item`. You aren't reusing the one declared with `Deque<Item>`. These may be different types. Instead, get rid of the parameter declaration

```
private class DequeIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
```

Presumably, `current.item` is a reference to an object of type `Item` declared in `Deque`, but you're trying to assign it to a variable of type `Item` declared in `DequeIterator`.

---

You'll also need to remove parameterizations of `DequeIterator` since it isn't generic any more. So, for example

```
return new DequeIterator<Item>();
```

changes to

```
return new DequeIterator();
```

Comment: thanks so much for your quick reply! removing `<Item>` gives me another compilation error: `Deque.DequeIterator does not take parameters  return new DequeIterator<Item>();`

Comment: @nburk Oh yeah, remove any parameterization of `DequeIterator`.